# Subtraction in a while loop

Tags: python, loops, subtraction

How can I subtract `1000` from my `max` variable so I decrement the
value each time it loops?

```
while 1:
    max = 160000
    players = []
    players.append(Player(202556,32000))
    randomPlayer = random.choice(players)
    time.sleep(random.randint(1,4))
    items = fut.searchAuctions('player',assetId=randomPlayer.assetId,
                               max_buy=randomPlayer.maxBid,max_price=max)
    max-1000
    print max
```

Comment: You should assign "max" before loop and decrement it inside loop like this: "max -= 1000"

Comment: Don't know what is with downvotes without reason. Why can't one ask basic questions!!

Comment: @DexTer Because these questions can be Google searched.  Honestly, this question isnt even programming related.  It's logic related.  Common sense almost.

Comment: @DexTer It depends how basic they are. SO isn't a substitute for tutorials to get the basics of a language.

Comment: Well, then such questions should be deleted during review itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move max outside of the while loop. Otherwise you will always restart the max with the same value. Then decrease the max value.

`max = 160000 # scope outside loop
 while 1:
   max -= 1000  # decrease variable
   print max`

Answer (score 1):

```
max-1000
```

must become

```
max -= 1000
```

Answer (score 1):

```
max-1000
```

Look at the statement here. You are substructing, but not assigning the new value. Do this:

```
max= max-1000
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to assign the new value of max to itself:

```
max = max-1000
```